# Can we have Power Apps and Power Automate inside SharePoint On-premises

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, power-automate, powerapp, power-platform, on-premise-data-gateway

We are working on a new SharePoint project, where the customer does not have any SharePoint licenses yet, and they want to use SharePoint **On-Premises**.

So I have the following questions, If can we use Power Apps and Power Automate inside SharePoint On-premises? If the answer is Yes, then what version of SharePoint On-premises we need to use?

Second question, If Power Apps is supported inside On-premises SharePoint, then can we use to build the following:

1. Customizing the lists/libraries forms?
2. Build Standalone canvas apps?
3. Build Responsive Power apps using the responsive feature provided such as horizontal and vertical containers?

Answer (score 1):

You can use on-premises data gateway to connect with SharePoint on-premises sites/lists in Power Apps and Power Automate.

Check below documentations for more information:

1. [What is an on-premises data gateway?](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/gateway-reference)
2. [Support for on-premises SharePoint lists](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/fr-be/blog/support-for-sharepoint-on-premises)

Using data gateway you can develop standalone canvas apps with responsive features as well. I don't have an on-premises server to test for list form customizations. But, most probably list form customizations will not be supported using Power apps. You can test it from your end after data gateway creation.

For more information, check: [SharePoint 2019 List form customization](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/sharepoint-2019-list-form-customization/m-p/1287908)

---

My recommendation will be to use the SharePoint 2019 as it is latest SharePoint on-premises version with modern experience.

Comment: ok thanks for the info, so will i be able to build the 3 points i mentioned in my question?

Comment: check updated answer for more information.

Comment: i also do not have 2019 environemnt

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MVP SharePoint 2021 aka SharePoint Subscription Edition (SPSE) is the latest on-premises version of SharePoint and is recommended.

Comment: Yes, correct: [Upgrade to SharePoint Server Subscription Edition](https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepoint/upgrade-and-update/upgrade-to-sharepoint-server-subscription-edition?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224).